# Run Apps script When CheckBox Checked

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Could someone assist with code that will run a script when the checkbox is checked. I have the script already and just need it triggered.

I could not see any that would do this on this website.

Thanks very much

Comment: Can you provide more details. It is not very clear from you question.

Comment: Try button instead of checkbox. Google it and [something like this](http://googleappscripting.com/google-spreadsheet-button/) can help you.